Does Gödel’s incompleteness theorems imply the necessity of an infinite recursive hierarchy of “proofs”, and that any “proof” is relative?
My understanding is that Gödel’s incompleteness theorems state that the consistency of any axiomatic system cannot be proven within that axiomatic system, and requires a stronger axiomatic system in order to prove its consistency. Let’s say that we have an axiomatic system and another, stronger axiomatic system that is capable of proving the first axiomatic system’s consistency. But doesn’t this second axiomatic system also require a stronger axiomatic system to prove its consistency in order for us to trust its result/proof of consistency for the first axiomatic system? And so on and so forth in a hierarchical, recursive fashion for all possible axiomatic systems, ad infinitum?
If so, then wouldn’t this reasoning show that we cannot actually (formally) “prove” anything, in an absolute sense, or that any “proof” is simply relative to some axiomatic system, since there exists this kind of fundamental hierarchical/recursive “dependency relation”? In other words, there is no “absolute anchoring”, so to speak — it’s all relative! At the risk of making a fool of myself, as I am not a physicist, it seems analogous to the physics space-time “frame of reference” situation, no?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Two good "semi-technical" introduction to the issue:

T.Franzen, Gödel's Theorem. An Incomplete Guide to Its Use and Abuse (2005) and

F.Berto, There's Something About Gödel (2009).


A complete treatment:

P.Smith, An Introduction to Gödel's Theorems (2013).

Regarding the never-ending hierarchy of theories, see:

T.Franzen, Inexhaustibility: A Non-Exhaustive Treatment (2004): Introduction, page 1:


Gödel presented two results in his 1931 paper, usually referred to as the first and the second incompleteness theorem. The proof of the first incompleteness theorem
shows that for every consistent formal axiomatic theory in a wide class of such theories, there is at least one statement which can be formulated in the language of the theory but can neither be proved nor disproved in the theory. [...] The second theorem states that for a wide class of such theories T, if T is consistent, the consistency of T cannot be proved using only the axioms of the theory T itself.


The second incompleteness theorem also has a
positive aspect, which was emphasized by Gödel (Collected Works, vol. III, p.309, italics in the original): "It is this theorem [the second incompleteness theorem] which makes the incompletability of mathematics particularly evident. For, it makes it impossible that someone should set up a certain well-defined system of axioms and rules and consistently make the following assertion about it: All of these axioms and rules I perceive (with mathematical certitude) to be correct, and moreover I believe that they contain all of mathematics. If somebody makes such a statement he contradicts himself. For if he perceives the axioms under consideration to be correct, he also perceives (with the same certainty) that they are consistent. Hence he has a mathematical insight not derivable from his axioms."


For Gödel’s incompleteness theorems, I’m currently studying Mathematical Logic: A course with exercises - Part I - Propositional Calculus, Boolean Algebras, Predicate Calculus, Completeness Theorems and Mathematical Logic: A Course with Exercises Part II: Recursion theory, Godel’s Theorems, Set theory, Model theory by René Cori and Daniel Lascar. How are the textbooks you recommended different?

@ThePointer - they are more specific, with discussione of the "philosophical" (good and bad) implications of the theorems. The one you are using is a textbook and GIT is a methametical result whose proof can be studied on many sources, Cori&Lascar included.


Does Gödel’s incompleteness theorems imply the necessity of an infinite recursive hierarchy of “proofs”, and that any “proof” is relative?

Gödel's proofs are based on a false logic so it doesn't prove anything. The more general point that an "axiomatic system cannot be proven within that axiomatic system, and requires a stronger axiomatic system" is trivial. Axioms are assumed true, but if we want to prove them, we need to assume another set of axioms, and so on ad infinitum. This is just how logic works.
However, even this is of little practical consequence, for reality decides which axioms are really true. We don't have to go into an infinite regress to prove our axioms. We only have to try and understand which is true of the reality and which is not.
Mathematicians are not minded to pay attention to what is really true and what is not. They prefer to fathom the logic of their axioms and this is all that seems to matter to them. Suit yourself.

In other words, there is no “absolute anchoring”, so to speak — it’s all relative! At the risk of making a fool of myself, as I am not a physicist, it seems analogous to the physics space-time “frame of reference” situation, no?

Not quite, no. Physicists still seem to favour assessing the truth of their theories against reality, and reality is nothing if not an "absolute anchoring".
Physicists take their measures to be relative to the frame of reference, but only because they take the speed of light be  . . . absolute.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

In what world is the principle of explosion false? How can you possibly conceive of or live in a universe without it? You understand so little, but claim so much. Try harder, and learn swallow your pride.

@PW_246 "In what world is the principle of explosion false?" The real world. - 2. "How can you possibly conceive of or live in a universe without it?" Humanity has managed to exist for more than 300,000 years without it and still today nobody has any application for it still today. - 3. "You understand so little, but claim so much. Try harder, and learn swallow your pride." Insults only prove you have no rational argument.

@Speakpigeon I and others have given you countless arguments and examples, but you always respond with the same BS that doesn’t add up to anything substantive. In the real world, if you do a contradiction (which you can’t), then you do anything. Nothing is off limits if a contradiction is true.

@Speakpigeon Have you never heard someone say “If that’s true, then I’m the King of England” or “I’ll believe that when pigs fly”? Those are examples of people identifying the principle of explosion as valid, even if it’s meant as a joke.

@PW_246 "In the real world, if you do a contradiction (which you can’t), then you do anything. Nothing is off limits if a contradiction is true." Whoa. This is absurd. And actually not even what the PoE itself says! Congratulation.

@PW_246 "someone say “If that’s true, then I’m the King of England” or “I’ll believe that when pigs fly”?" Sure, I'm very familiar with those. It is funny that this is something people do in any language! - 2. "Those are examples of people identifying the principle of explosion as valid, even if it’s meant as a joke." Don't be silly. If you were a little bit interested in the proper explanation you would have searched the Internet as I did and found as I did at least one guy who gives it; apparently unaware he was saying something most academic would-be logicians are unable to articulate.

What are you even talking about?

@Speakpigeon it’s a colloquial form of reductio. That’s it, that’s all.

@PW_246 "it’s a colloquial form of reductio" And I agree, but the reductio has nothing to do with the PoE.

@Speakpigeon Reductio has everything to do with the principle of explosion. If you can boil something down to a contradiction, then anything else follows, just like if someone makes an absurd claim, then you can validly make fun of their claim by saying that it implies something crazy.

@PW_246 "Reductio has everything to do with the principle of explosion. If you can boil something down to a contradiction, then anything else follows, just like if someone makes an absurd claim, then you can validly make fun of their claim by saying that it implies something crazy." You are repeating yourself. Ever so vaguely. We disagree. I'm right. You're wrong. There is nothing else to say.

@Speakpigeon I repeat myself because you never actually have anything to say to me, so I have to find new ways of making the same point. The point being that a comparison of one’s claim to an impossible scenario is logically grounded in the principle of explosion. Logic has a normative element. Humans are not perfectly logical; we have to accept when something is saying what it says truly. Noting is false if a contradiction is true, and since not-false is true, everything is true if a contradiction is true. This follows obviously from the principle of implosion, DeMorgan’s and contraposition.

@PW_246 "comparison of one’s claim to an impossible scenario is logically grounded in the principle of explosion" Don't understand. - 2. "Logic has a normative element" You bet. - 3. "Humans are not perfectly logical" Absurd. If that was true, no one could possibly understand logic. - 4. "we have to accept when something is saying what it says truly" Don't understand. - 5. "Noting is false if a contradiction is true" Bad English. Try good English. - 6. "since not-false is true, everything is true if a contradiction is true." Non sequitur. So overall zero marks for English & logic.

@PW_246 "This follows obviously from the principle of implosion, DeMorgan’s and contraposition" Obviously not. Nothing follows from De Morgan’s laws or from contraposition etc. Never mind from the PoE. Your discussion of the PoE suffers from your bad English. Your English is really not very good. Yet, English is clearly your mother tongue. I suspect that your failure to understand logic goes with your bad English. A sort of common unkemptness. It is funny that you should claim that humans are not perfectly logical at the same time that you think you can teach logic! Perhaps bad logic?

@Speakpigeon Give me one example of poor English on my part, and I’ll fly on to the moon. Maybe you just can’t understand me, which is fine, since English obviously isn’t your first language. Aside from all of that, what could you possibly mean that nothing follows from DeMorgan’s? Maybe I should have said “…follows obviously by….” Either way, the point is that as long as you believe that DeMorgan’s, contraposition, and the principle of implosion are valid, you must believe in at least a version of the PoE.

@Speakpigeon You think perfect  logical understanding is necessary for any logical understanding? You actually believe that humans are logically infallible? I’m at a loss for words, if that’s so.

You clearly understood what I meant, but if a typo is worth mentioning, your point clearly does not stand. With that said, it must be the case that nothing is false if a contradiction is true, and thereby (hint, it’s not a non-sequitur, but apparently your brain can’t handle actual argumentation) it must be the case that something not-false under is true under those same circumstances. Make an attempt to understand my argument before bi***ing about typos.

@PW_246 "about typos" I didn't say typos. I said bad English. Conclusions possibly follow by for example the modus ponens, not from the modus ponens. So nothing follows from De Morgan’s laws. And, it is not because A follows from B and that B is true, that A is true. That would be asserting the consequent, and this is recognised as bad logic. So when you say "This follows obviously from the principle of implosion, etc.", I say who cares. The point is that we don't need the PoE to explain anything because we have the Reductio. Anyway, waste of time.

@Speakpigeon There is no circularity or affirming the consequent. The point is that you can do basic logic and arrive at the conclusion that the PoE is valid. It has nothing to do with what we need as rational agents and everything to do with the fact that some things about logic are true regardless of what we think about them. You can’t consistently just choose some valid argument forms and throw out the rest, especially when argument forms you agree with are sufficient to validate some that you don’t agree with.

@Speakpigeon Also, qua principle explosion does follow from DeMorgan’s etc. That is if you assume certain formulas as valid that correspond to the argument forms I mentioned, over some simple rules you’ll be able to derive explosion.

@PW_246 "principle explosion does follow from DeMorgan’s etc." Don't be silly. 2. "some things about logic are true regardless of what we think about them." Exactly. For example, you think that the PoE is a logical principle and yet it is not. 3. "You can’t consistently just choose . . . some that you don’t agree with." Good, I don't do that. 4. "you’ll be able to derive explosion." Not logically, no. The only proof I am aware of is just illogical. Pathetically illogical.

@Speakpigeon The proof on wiki is valid, but I’ll provide an alternative proof that goes along with what I’ve been telling you, though you’ve been refusing to listen. Please tell me exactly which step is “illogical”.                                              1.¬Q→(P∨¬P) [PoI]
2.¬(P∨¬P)→Q [1, Contraposition]
3.(¬P∧¬¬P)→Q [2, DeMorgan’s]
4.(P∧¬P)→Q [3, Double Negation, Commutativity of ∧]

@Speakpigeon Since you’ll probably nitpick, note that the final justification technically uses rules that I didn’t mention, but I’m sure you agree with them anyway.

@PW_246 "1.¬Q→(P∨¬P) [PoI] 2.¬(P∨¬P)→Q [1, Contraposition] 3.(¬P∧¬¬P)→Q [2, DeMorgan’s] 4.(P∧¬P)→Q [3, Double Negation, Commutativity of ∧]" Ah, lovely! Where did you get that? Has it been published in the academic literature?

@Speakpigeon I learned it probably for the first time in high school, but I don’t think it’s published anywhere since it’s considered trivial. Maybe Russell took the time to prove it, but I really don’t know.

@PW_246 "I don’t think it’s published anywhere" Ok, so academics can always deny they ever proposed that proof.
